# Best way to integrate bootstrap with symfony3

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, symfony

I know how to use bootstrap with symfony without any bundles: download bootstrap, put compiled css and js files under web directory and its ready to use, working fine.

However I would like to use LESS or SASS mixins, in order not to use bootstrap classes like "row" or "column-X-Y", but my own, and include bootstrap CSS inside it. Some time ago I tried it with LESS and it was nightmare - every LESS change was compiling very long time. Also I had to compile it manually in console.

I tried MOPA bootstrap bundle, but it wasn't working well (I'm using symfony3).

Any suggestion on how to do that best way ?

Comment: This has nothing to do with Symfony, or even PHP. I would suggest to use Grunt or Gulp  watch task, to compile less on every file save. Alternatively IDE may have built-in support for compiling less/sass. Try with google. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is the asset manager Assetic. This is not included by default in symfony3, but check out this page for more information:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/assetic/php.html.

Assetic enables you to compile and minify resources. The documentation page linked to even uses the bootstrap library as an example.